# Can we have a more printer friendly profile?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page, printing

So I just printed my Stack Overflow profile on paper, so that I can include it with my resume.

It looks OK. Except for the badges. They're all more or less black and white!

Here is a scan I took of the print:

[image: badges on printed profile]

I printed it in **color**. The first two pages showed fine but like I said, the badges show up without any color.

As a slight digression of this post, maybe we can have more Stack Overflow info on Careers.

I was just hoping to show off some rep, my top answers (these are covered in Careers) and my badges (which are not).

Could we optionally include badges and maybe a more Stack Overflow-centric careers? After all Careers is for programmers so showing off your Stack Overflow profile matters more than other SE websites.

Just my 2¢ though. I'm going for my interview with black and white badges.

Comment: A 'printer friendly' version of a Careers SO profile might be the better route, since we can cherry pick our 'greatest hits' for inclusion in our listing there (and pointy haired bosses can print out stuff they find interesting) .. Ok, not so sure on the PHB point.

Comment: true. Optionally adding your badges in there would be nice. (Maybe a little informal/funny) but nice.

Comment: Well, the only important badge (to an employer) is in black on white text :)

Comment: What's a printer?

Comment: @will whyy its a big 'ol box that draws things on this other thing called paper. Like this one here : http://theoatmeal.com/comics/printers